# Receive data in Php from Ajax jQuery File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know some basic of `php`. But I have never used `ajax`. Now, I got one contact file in which they are passing data to `php` file using ajax. I really don't have any idea about how to do this.
Please help me regarding this.
**contact.js :**

```
$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url : "send.php",    
             data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + "You Got Email" + "&message=" + message,
             success: function(data){    
              if(data == 'success'){
                $("#btnsubmit").remove();
                $("#mail_success").fadeIn(500);
              }else{
                $("#mail_failed").html(data).fadeIn(500);
                $("#send").removeAttr("disabled").attr("value", "send");
              }     
             }  
           });
```

I don't know if it is right but I know this much so I have created send.php file myself. Check this.

**send.php :**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$mail_sub= $subject;
$mail_from = "$email"; // applicant email id. it must be dynamic.

$mail_body = "<html> <body>";
$mail_body .= '<table style="" cellpadding="3">';
$mail_body .= "
                <tr>
                <td width='120'> <strong> Name </strong> </td>
                <td width='8'> : </td>
                <td width='300'> $name </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> <strong> Email </strong> </td>
                <td> : </td>
                <td> $email </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> <strong> Message </strong> </td>
                <td> : </td>
                <td> $message </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </body> </html>"; 

$header = "From: $name<$email>\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
$header .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
$header .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP / ".phpversion()."\r\n";
$header .= "Importance: High\n";

$mail_to= 'in@example.com'; // receiver email address.

?>
```

How to achieve this ? I want to send email and want to return message as per js file.

Comment: exactly what do you want to achieve? this script should be working as it is... you're just not sending the mail

Comment: You have to escape (encode) each `POST` parameter or use `serialize()` method if they come from `form` elements

Comment: Just echo "success" or echo "failure" after you sent your email. That should do it

Comment: @hindmost, I am getting all values on contact.js file. I have not written that code here.

Comment: @SjoerdDeWit,How can i know exception in php ?

Answer (score 0):

phppart

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$mail_sub= $subject;
$mail_from = "$email"; // applicant email id. it must be dynamic.

$mail_body = "<html> <body>";
$mail_body .= '<table style="" cellpadding="3">';
$mail_body .= "
                <tr>
                <td width='120'> <strong> Name </strong> </td>
                <td width='8'> : </td>
                <td width='300'> $name </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> <strong> Email </strong> </td>
                <td> : </td>
                <td> $email </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> <strong> Message </strong> </td>
                <td> : </td>
                <td> $message </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </body> </html>"; 

$header = "From: $name<$email>\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
$header .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
$header .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP / ".phpversion()."\r\n";
$header .= "Importance: High\n";

$mail_to= 'in@example.com'; // receiver email address.

$isvalid = false;
if(mail($mail_to, $mailsub, $mail_body, $header)){
  $isvalid = true;
}
echo json_encode($isvalid);
```

jquery part

```
$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url : "send.php",    
             data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + "You Got Email" + "&message=" + message,
             success: function(data){
              var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              if(response.isvalid == true){
                $("#btnsubmit").remove();
                $("#mail_success").fadeIn(500);
              }else{
                $("#mail_failed").html(data).fadeIn(500);
                $("#send").removeAttr("disabled").attr("value", "send");
              }     
             }  
           });
```

Andd umm that should do it!